# Calling a variable outside a class

Tags: python, maya

How can I get the value of an `intSliderGrp` defined inside a class and use it on a function outside said class?

I'm trying to get my main UI all inside a class so I can just call it inside maya, but I need the value set on a slider to modify a function outside the classUI:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

def setSubdivision(*args):
    obj = cmds.ls(sl = True)
    asubd = cmds.intSliderGrp(sliderSet, query = True , value = True)
    for i in obj:
        cmds.setAttr('%s.aiSubdivIterations' %i, int(asubd))
        
class subdivisionUI():
    
    windowName = "ArnoldSubdivisionWindow"

    def show(self):

        if cmds.window(self.windowName, query =  True, exists =  True, width = 150):
            cmds.deleteUI(self.windowName)

        cmds.window(self.windowName)
        
        mainColumn = cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn = True)
        
        cmds.text(l='Set subdivisions to selected objects', al = 'center')

        column2 = cmds.rowLayout(numberOfColumns = 2, adjustableColumn=2, columnAlign=(1, 'right'))
        sliderSet = cmds.intSliderGrp(l = "Subdivisions", s =1, min = 0, max = 20, field = True)
        b = cmds.button(l = 'Set')
        cmds.button(b, e = True , command = setSubdivision, width = 50 ) 

        

        cmds.showWindow()
        
        
subdivisionUI().show()
```

It's my first time using classes so I'm still trying to understand how they work and the proper use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment you do not use the advantage of classes for UI creation in Maya. The big advantage is that you can keep everything encapsulated in this class without the need of any external functions or global variables. If you try this approach your problem disappears:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

        
class subdivisionUI():
    
    windowName = "ArnoldSubdivisionWindow"
    
    def __init__(self):
        if cmds.window(self.windowName, query =  True, exists =  True, width = 150):
            cmds.deleteUI(self.windowName)

        self.window = cmds.window(self.windowName)
        mainColumn = cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn = True)
        cmds.text(l='Set subdivisions to selected objects', al = 'center')

        column2 = cmds.rowLayout(numberOfColumns = 2, adjustableColumn=2, columnAlign=(1, 'right'))
        self.sliderSet = cmds.intSliderGrp(l = "Subdivisions", s =1, min = 0, max = 20, field = True)
        b = cmds.button(l = 'Set')
        cmds.button(b, e = True , command = self.setSubdivision, width = 50 ) 
        
    def setSubdivision(self, *args):
        obj = cmds.ls(sl = True)
        asubd = cmds.intSliderGrp(self.sliderSet, query = True , value = True)
        for i in obj:
            cmds.setAttr('%s.aiSubdivIterations' %i, int(asubd))

    def show(self):
        cmds.showWindow(self.window)
        
        
subdivisionUI().show()
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense, I tried this with the rest of my code and worked perfectly. I'm still trying  to figure out the different uses of a class and "self". But this gives me an overall idea. Thank you!